# os.tmpDir() is deprecated - node and formidable

Tags: node.js, formidable

I use node version 7.2.0 and formidable version 1.0.17 for file upload. After updating to the node version 7.2.0 I now get the following error when uploading files:

`(node:3376) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.`

I don't use the default of `form.uploadDir` but some custom path.

How would I fix that error?

Comment: It's not really an error, it's a deprecation warning. You can ask the formidable maintainers to fix it or you could just put something like the following at the top of your file: `var os = require('os'); os.tmpDir = os.tmpdir;`

Comment: @idbhold: Many thanks. That worked!

Comment: @idbhold, thanks. Don't know why the warning is shown as an error.

Answer (score 16):

@idbehold, it worked like a charm.

> It's not really an error, it's a deprecation warning. You can ask the formidable maintainers to fix it or you could just put something like the following at the top of your file:
>
> `var os = require('os');`
>
> `os.tmpDir = os.tmpdir;`