# )}; error in conf.js file when running protractor doesn't match script

Tags: angular, testing, protractor

I feel like I've bracketed my conf.js file correctly but when adding parameters I'm getting a syntax error as if I have an extra parenthesis/bracket combination when I don't think I have one.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
// conf.js
//var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
var os = require('os'); os.tmpDir = os.tmpdir;


exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['qaSpec.js'],

  //module.exports = { 
  params: {
    login: {
      url: 'http://phptravels.com/demo/',
      // username: 'juliel@ibm.com',
      //password: 'password' 

    }
  }
};
```

I've commented out username and password for now, but if I uncomment them I get

DepreciationWarning: os.tmpDir is depriciated, use os.tmpdir instead

I tried putting in the fix from here: [os.tmpDir() is deprecated - node and formidable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913034/os-tmpdir-is-deprecated-node-and-formidable), but still getting the os.tmpDir issue

To focus on one thing at a time, though, why is it indicating there is `});` at line 19 when it's clearly `};` and why is this a problem?

Comment: the file you posted has only 15 lines so hard to tell which one is line 19

Comment: the rest of the file will definitely help to detect the problem. are you on vs code ?

Comment: Not sure what that vs code is honestly but I can edit this to include my spec file, I just assumed that it was failing at conf.js from the error. Line 19 is the last line, edited for clarification

Comment: So, update, exports.config doesn't seem to like params being within the function. I seperate config and params into seperate functions and I get an error saying there is a problem with username. It says unexpected token ':'. It doesn't seem to say there's a problem with a colon after the url, only username. I'm baffled.